# javascript charset for object attributes

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an object runtime:

```
var myObj = {};
myObj[propertyName] = propertyValue;
```

propertyName is something variable, and if it's like "a.b" my object has the "a" property with the "b" subproperty. So I was thinking about a regexp to clean the data, but I need to know what others characters may be problematic for javascript.

Comment: `myObj["a.b"]` create a property called `a.b` . it's not recursive .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What characters are valid for JavaScript variable names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know if you create it with bracket notation, `myObj['a.b']` is a valid single property of `myObj` object.

Here is your reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties